# Как заставить работать href?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть такой вот код, добавляющий кнопку в приложение.

```js
var Arrive=function(e,t,n){"use strict";function r(e,t,n){l.addMethod(t,n,e.unbindEvent),l.addMethod(t,n,e.unbindEventWithSelectorOrCallback),l.addMethod(t,n,e.unbindEventWithSelectorAndCallback)}function i(e){e.arrive=f.bindEvent,r(f,e,"unbindArrive"),e.leave=d.bindEvent,r(d,e,"unbindLeave")}if(e.MutationObserver&&"undefined"!=typeof HTMLElement){var o=0,l=function(){var t=HTMLElement.prototype.matches||HTMLElement.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector||HTMLElement.prototype.mozMatchesSelector||HTMLElement.prototype.msMatchesSelector;return{matchesSelector:function(e,n){return e instanceof HTMLElement&&t.call(e,n)},addMethod:function(e,t,r){var i=e[t];e[t]=function(){return r.length==arguments.length?r.apply(this,arguments):"function"==typeof i?i.apply(this,arguments):n}},callCallbacks:function(e,t){t&&t.options.onceOnly&&1==t.firedElems.length&&(e=[e[0]]);for(var n,r=0;n=e[r];r++)n&&n.callback&&n.callback.call(n.elem,n.elem);t&&t.options.onceOnly&&1==t.firedElems.length&&t.me.unbindEventWithSelectorAndCallback.call(t.target,t.selector,t.callback)},checkChildNodesRecursively:function(e,t,n,r){for(var i,o=0;i=e[o];o++)n(i,t,r)&&r.push({callback:t.callback,elem:i}),i.childNodes.length>0&&l.checkChildNodesRecursively(i.childNodes,t,n,r)},mergeArrays:function(e,t){var n,r={};for(n in e)e.hasOwnProperty(n)&&(r[n]=e[n]);for(n in t)t.hasOwnProperty(n)&&(r[n]=t[n]);return r},toElementsArray:function(t){return n===t||"number"==typeof t.length&&t!==e||(t=[t]),t}}}(),c=function(){var e=function(){this._eventsBucket=[],this._beforeAdding=null,this._beforeRemoving=null};return e.prototype.addEvent=function(e,t,n,r){var i={target:e,selector:t,options:n,callback:r,firedElems:[]};return this._beforeAdding&&this._beforeAdding(i),this._eventsBucket.push(i),i},e.prototype.removeEvent=function(e){for(var t,n=this._eventsBucket.length-1;t=this._eventsBucket[n];n--)if(e(t)){this._beforeRemoving&&this._beforeRemoving(t);var r=this._eventsBucket.splice(n,1);r&&r.length&&(r[0].callback=null)}},e.prototype.beforeAdding=function(e){this._beforeAdding=e},e.prototype.beforeRemoving=function(e){this._beforeRemoving=e},e}(),a=function(t,r){var i=new c,o=this,a={fireOnAttributesModification:!1};return i.beforeAdding(function(n){var i,l=n.target;(l===e.document||l===e)&&(l=document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0]),i=new MutationObserver(function(e){r.call(this,e,n)});var c=t(n.options);i.observe(l,c),n.observer=i,n.me=o}),i.beforeRemoving(function(e){e.observer.disconnect()}),this.bindEvent=function(e,t,n){t=l.mergeArrays(a,t);for(var r=l.toElementsArray(this),o=0;o<r.length;o++)i.addEvent(r[o],e,t,n)},this.unbindEvent=function(){var e=l.toElementsArray(this);i.removeEvent(function(t){for(var r=0;r<e.length;r++)if(this===n||t.target===e[r])return!0;return!1})},this.unbindEventWithSelectorOrCallback=function(e){var t,r=l.toElementsArray(this),o=e;t="function"==typeof e?function(e){for(var t=0;t<r.length;t++)if((this===n||e.target===r[t])&&e.callback===o)return!0;return!1}:function(t){for(var i=0;i<r.length;i++)if((this===n||t.target===r[i])&&t.selector===e)return!0;return!1},i.removeEvent(t)},this.unbindEventWithSelectorAndCallback=function(e,t){var r=l.toElementsArray(this);i.removeEvent(function(i){for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)if((this===n||i.target===r[o])&&i.selector===e&&i.callback===t)return!0;return!1})},this},s=function(){function e(e){var t={attributes:!1,childList:!0,subtree:!0};return e.fireOnAttributesModification&&(t.attributes=!0),t}function t(e,t){e.forEach(function(e){var n=e.addedNodes,i=e.target,o=[];null!==n&&n.length>0?l.checkChildNodesRecursively(n,t,r,o):"attributes"===e.type&&r(i,t,o)&&o.push({callback:t.callback,elem:i}),l.callCallbacks(o,t)})}function r(e,t){return l.matchesSelector(e,t.selector)&&(e._id===n&&(e._id=o++),-1==t.firedElems.indexOf(e._id))?(t.firedElems.push(e._id),!0):!1}var i={fireOnAttributesModification:!1,onceOnly:!1,existing:!1};f=new a(e,t);var c=f.bindEvent;return f.bindEvent=function(e,t,r){n===r?(r=t,t=i):t=l.mergeArrays(i,t);var o=l.toElementsArray(this);if(t.existing){for(var a=[],s=0;s<o.length;s++)for(var u=o[s].querySelectorAll(e),f=0;f<u.length;f++)a.push({callback:r,elem:u[f]});if(t.onceOnly&&a.length)return r.call(a[0].elem,a[0].elem);setTimeout(l.callCallbacks,1,a)}c.call(this,e,t,r)},f},u=function(){function e(){var e={childList:!0,subtree:!0};return e}function t(e,t){e.forEach(function(e){var n=e.removedNodes,i=[];null!==n&&n.length>0&&l.checkChildNodesRecursively(n,t,r,i),l.callCallbacks(i,t)})}function r(e,t){return l.matchesSelector(e,t.selector)}var i={};d=new a(e,t);var o=d.bindEvent;return d.bindEvent=function(e,t,r){n===r?(r=t,t=i):t=l.mergeArrays(i,t),o.call(this,e,t,r)},d},f=new s,d=new u;t&&i(t.fn),i(HTMLElement.prototype),i(NodeList.prototype),i(HTMLCollection.prototype),i(HTMLDocument.prototype),i(Window.prototype);var h={};return r(f,h,"unbindAllArrive"),r(d,h,"unbindAllLeave"),h}}(window,"undefined"==typeof jQuery?null:jQuery,void 0);


function actionofButton(){
}

function addButton(){
  var ExtraControlsDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('ExtraControls')[0];
  
  var newDIv = document.createElement("div");
  var button = document.createElement("button");
  button.classList.add("control-button");
  button.setAttribute('href','/lyrics-plus')             // <--------------------
  button.innerHTML = `
          <svg role="img" height="16" width="16" viewBox="0 -1 16 16" style="fill:currentcolor">
            <path d="M8.5 1A4.505 4.505 0 004 5.5c0 .731.191 1.411.502 2.022L1.99 13.163a1.307 1.307 0 00.541 1.666l.605.349a1.307 1.307 0 001.649-.283L9.009 9.95C11.248 9.692 13 7.807 13 5.5 13 3.019 10.981 1 8.5 1zM4.023 14.245a.307.307 0 01-.388.066l-.605-.349a.309.309 0 01-.128-.393l2.26-5.078A4.476 4.476 0 007.715 9.92l-3.692 4.325zM8.5 9C6.57 9 5 7.43 5 5.5S6.57 2 8.5 2 12 3.57 12 5.5 10.429 9 8.5 9z">
            </path>
          </svg>
        </button>`;
  newDIv.appendChild(button);//adds the button to the end of the div
  newDIv.addEventListener("click", actionofButton);

  ExtraControlsDiv.insertBefore(newDIv, ExtraControlsDiv.firstElementChild)//inserts the div created into the panel, before all the other buttons
}

document.arrive(".ReactModalPortal", function(){//on full page arrival, since seems it loads the page twice for some reason
  addButton();
  Arrive.unbindAllArrive();//because uncertain if document.unbindArrive(".ReactModalPortal") actually works.
})
```

Нужно, что бы при нажатии перекидывало на /lyrics-plus (в приложении), я стрелкой указал, куда добавил `button.setAttribute('href','/lyrics-plus')` но при нажатии ничего не происходит. Либо я не туда добавил, либо вообще не то добавил. В общем, покажите пожалуйста, как правильно.

P.S. HTML код похожей кнопки. При нажатии делает именно то, что нужно - перекидывает на /lyrics-plus внутри приложения.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Откуда у button атрибут href?

Comment: согласен с @АлексейШиманский, для того чтобы поставить ссылку можете использовать <form method="GET" action="index.html"><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></form>

Comment: `button.setAttribute('onclick', 'window.location.href="/lyrics-plus"')`, но в идеале другое что-то придумать

Comment: @InDevX Хм. Это кнопка в приложении, и перекидывать должно на страницу в приложении, а так почему то перекидывает в браузер...

Comment: "Это кнопка в приложении, и перекидывать должно на страницу в приложении, а так почему то перекидывает в браузер" - я ничего не понял.

Comment: @FiftyFour7250 что за приложение? Добавляйте a вместо button, просто стилизируйте ссылку под кнопку

Comment: @Igor Вот подобная кнопка, и при нажатии она перекидывает на страницу в приложении. 
https://a.radikal.ru/a06/2105/cf/50d453eee003.png

Вариант, предложенный выше - при нажатии почему то открывает вкладку в браузере, и пытается загрузить этот /lyrics-plus там, а не в приложении.

Comment: @FiftyFour7250 Кхм, кхм. Я не буду ходить ни по каким сомнительным ссылкам. А "приложение" что, не в браузере?

Comment: @Igor, Нет, это настольный клиент Спотифая для Windows. Скриншот из "сомнительной ссылки" добавил в вопрос.

Comment: Скриншот из сомнительной ссылки показывает нам, что там используют тег "а", а не кнопку https://i.imgur.com/ITm4ri6.jpg

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Так как уже есть кнопка с такой же ссылкой, то нужно просто нажать её.

```js
var Arrive=function(e,t,n){"use strict";function r(e,t,n){l.addMethod(t,n,e.unbindEvent),l.addMethod(t,n,e.unbindEventWithSelectorOrCallback),l.addMethod(t,n,e.unbindEventWithSelectorAndCallback)}function i(e){e.arrive=f.bindEvent,r(f,e,"unbindArrive"),e.leave=d.bindEvent,r(d,e,"unbindLeave")}if(e.MutationObserver&&"undefined"!=typeof HTMLElement){var o=0,l=function(){var t=HTMLElement.prototype.matches||HTMLElement.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector||HTMLElement.prototype.mozMatchesSelector||HTMLElement.prototype.msMatchesSelector;return{matchesSelector:function(e,n){return e instanceof HTMLElement&&t.call(e,n)},addMethod:function(e,t,r){var i=e[t];e[t]=function(){return r.length==arguments.length?r.apply(this,arguments):"function"==typeof i?i.apply(this,arguments):n}},callCallbacks:function(e,t){t&&t.options.onceOnly&&1==t.firedElems.length&&(e=[e[0]]);for(var n,r=0;n=e[r];r++)n&&n.callback&&n.callback.call(n.elem,n.elem);t&&t.options.onceOnly&&1==t.firedElems.length&&t.me.unbindEventWithSelectorAndCallback.call(t.target,t.selector,t.callback)},checkChildNodesRecursively:function(e,t,n,r){for(var i,o=0;i=e[o];o++)n(i,t,r)&&r.push({callback:t.callback,elem:i}),i.childNodes.length>0&&l.checkChildNodesRecursively(i.childNodes,t,n,r)},mergeArrays:function(e,t){var n,r={};for(n in e)e.hasOwnProperty(n)&&(r[n]=e[n]);for(n in t)t.hasOwnProperty(n)&&(r[n]=t[n]);return r},toElementsArray:function(t){return n===t||"number"==typeof t.length&&t!==e||(t=[t]),t}}}(),c=function(){var e=function(){this._eventsBucket=[],this._beforeAdding=null,this._beforeRemoving=null};return e.prototype.addEvent=function(e,t,n,r){var i={target:e,selector:t,options:n,callback:r,firedElems:[]};return this._beforeAdding&&this._beforeAdding(i),this._eventsBucket.push(i),i},e.prototype.removeEvent=function(e){for(var t,n=this._eventsBucket.length-1;t=this._eventsBucket[n];n--)if(e(t)){this._beforeRemoving&&this._beforeRemoving(t);var r=this._eventsBucket.splice(n,1);r&&r.length&&(r[0].callback=null)}},e.prototype.beforeAdding=function(e){this._beforeAdding=e},e.prototype.beforeRemoving=function(e){this._beforeRemoving=e},e}(),a=function(t,r){var i=new c,o=this,a={fireOnAttributesModification:!1};return i.beforeAdding(function(n){var i,l=n.target;(l===e.document||l===e)&&(l=document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0]),i=new MutationObserver(function(e){r.call(this,e,n)});var c=t(n.options);i.observe(l,c),n.observer=i,n.me=o}),i.beforeRemoving(function(e){e.observer.disconnect()}),this.bindEvent=function(e,t,n){t=l.mergeArrays(a,t);for(var r=l.toElementsArray(this),o=0;o<r.length;o++)i.addEvent(r[o],e,t,n)},this.unbindEvent=function(){var e=l.toElementsArray(this);i.removeEvent(function(t){for(var r=0;r<e.length;r++)if(this===n||t.target===e[r])return!0;return!1})},this.unbindEventWithSelectorOrCallback=function(e){var t,r=l.toElementsArray(this),o=e;t="function"==typeof e?function(e){for(var t=0;t<r.length;t++)if((this===n||e.target===r[t])&&e.callback===o)return!0;return!1}:function(t){for(var i=0;i<r.length;i++)if((this===n||t.target===r[i])&&t.selector===e)return!0;return!1},i.removeEvent(t)},this.unbindEventWithSelectorAndCallback=function(e,t){var r=l.toElementsArray(this);i.removeEvent(function(i){for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)if((this===n||i.target===r[o])&&i.selector===e&&i.callback===t)return!0;return!1})},this},s=function(){function e(e){var t={attributes:!1,childList:!0,subtree:!0};return e.fireOnAttributesModification&&(t.attributes=!0),t}function t(e,t){e.forEach(function(e){var n=e.addedNodes,i=e.target,o=[];null!==n&&n.length>0?l.checkChildNodesRecursively(n,t,r,o):"attributes"===e.type&&r(i,t,o)&&o.push({callback:t.callback,elem:i}),l.callCallbacks(o,t)})}function r(e,t){return l.matchesSelector(e,t.selector)&&(e._id===n&&(e._id=o++),-1==t.firedElems.indexOf(e._id))?(t.firedElems.push(e._id),!0):!1}var i={fireOnAttributesModification:!1,onceOnly:!1,existing:!1};f=new a(e,t);var c=f.bindEvent;return f.bindEvent=function(e,t,r){n===r?(r=t,t=i):t=l.mergeArrays(i,t);var o=l.toElementsArray(this);if(t.existing){for(var a=[],s=0;s<o.length;s++)for(var u=o[s].querySelectorAll(e),f=0;f<u.length;f++)a.push({callback:r,elem:u[f]});if(t.onceOnly&&a.length)return r.call(a[0].elem,a[0].elem);setTimeout(l.callCallbacks,1,a)}c.call(this,e,t,r)},f},u=function(){function e(){var e={childList:!0,subtree:!0};return e}function t(e,t){e.forEach(function(e){var n=e.removedNodes,i=[];null!==n&&n.length>0&&l.checkChildNodesRecursively(n,t,r,i),l.callCallbacks(i,t)})}function r(e,t){return l.matchesSelector(e,t.selector)}var i={};d=new a(e,t);var o=d.bindEvent;return d.bindEvent=function(e,t,r){n===r?(r=t,t=i):t=l.mergeArrays(i,t),o.call(this,e,t,r)},d},f=new s,d=new u;t&&i(t.fn),i(HTMLElement.prototype),i(NodeList.prototype),i(HTMLCollection.prototype),i(HTMLDocument.prototype),i(Window.prototype);var h={};return r(f,h,"unbindAllArrive"),r(d,h,"unbindAllLeave"),h}}(window,"undefined"==typeof jQuery?null:jQuery,void 0);


function actionofButton(){
   document.querySelector("a[href='/lyrics-plus']").click();             // <--------------------
}

function addButton(){
  var ExtraControlsDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('ExtraControls')[0];
  
  var newDIv = document.createElement("div");
  var button = document.createElement("button");
  button.classList.add("control-button");
  button.innerHTML = `
          <svg role="img" height="16" width="16" viewBox="0 -1 16 16" style="fill:currentcolor">
            <path d="M8.5 1A4.505 4.505 0 004 5.5c0 .731.191 1.411.502 2.022L1.99 13.163a1.307 1.307 0 00.541 1.666l.605.349a1.307 1.307 0 001.649-.283L9.009 9.95C11.248 9.692 13 7.807 13 5.5 13 3.019 10.981 1 8.5 1zM4.023 14.245a.307.307 0 01-.388.066l-.605-.349a.309.309 0 01-.128-.393l2.26-5.078A4.476 4.476 0 007.715 9.92l-3.692 4.325zM8.5 9C6.57 9 5 7.43 5 5.5S6.57 2 8.5 2 12 3.57 12 5.5 10.429 9 8.5 9z">
            </path>
          </svg>
        </button>`;
  newDIv.appendChild(button);//adds the button to the end of the div
  newDIv.addEventListener("click", actionofButton);

  ExtraControlsDiv.insertBefore(newDIv, ExtraControlsDiv.firstElementChild)//inserts the div created into the panel, before all the other buttons
}

document.arrive(".ReactModalPortal", function(){//on full page arrival, since seems it loads the page twice for some reason
  addButton();
  Arrive.unbindAllArrive();//because uncertain if document.unbindArrive(".ReactModalPortal") actually works.
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю как работает  настольный клиент Спотифая для Windows. Для меня это выглядит как обычный html в браузере. Возможно клиент работает через какой-нибудь Web View (по сути это и есть браузер, хоть и невидимый).

Что знаю по самой кнопке непосредственное в html (а точнее о гиперссылке в виде `a href`), так это то, что с некоторых пор у браузеров запрещена возможность клика по гиперссылке программно, **если эта гиперссылка была добавлена динамически в html** (не могу найти сейчас ссылку на то, где это рассказывается, но просто поверьте :)). Видимо это связано из-за возможности взлома или создания фишинговых страниц или отдаче юзерам скрипта, где прописаны данные манипуляции и тем самым что-то у людей кралось.

В ранних версиях браузеров работало много вещей, например:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = url;
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

или навешивая слушатели

```
.addEventListener("click",function(){
        ....
});
```

создавая всякие события через `CustomEvent` и выполнять клик.

Нет. На **динамически** созданную ссылку программный клик не сделать.

---

Всё что можно сделать это заранее прописать ссылку на страницу и:

- либо поменять в ней `href` и кликнуть программно (например по спрятанной кнопке)
- либо поменять в ней `href` и сказать пользователю чтоб он кликал))

---

И если приложение работает через Web View или подобное, то, скорее всего, правила действуют ровно такие же и поэтому работать это не будет, кроме подхода, описанного выше.

Comment: А если рассматривать вариант с a тэгом, то как это будет в коде выглядеть?

То ли я не туда воткнул 
`(var aElememt = document.createElement('a');`
Но после `(button.appendChild(aElement);` кнопка исчезла вообще :c

Comment: @FiftyFour7250 почему вы вставляете её в button?  `var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = 'https://google.com';
link.text = 111;
link.target='_blank';
document.body.appendChild(link);`   вместо `document.body` - какой-то другой тег. Но явно не в кнопку

Comment: Всё равно открывает в браузере. Не знаю, возможно тут вообще со всем кодом что то не так, а может в самом Спотифае что то не так. В общем, спасибо, буду дальше копать

Comment: уж не знаю  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯    попробуйте ещё без `link.target='_blank'`